# How to remove white space between iframe and div

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe

I'm trying to remove the white space between the `iframe` and `div` as I can. Initially there are a huge white space, but after adding in `margin: 0px;` to my `iframe`, `div`, and `h1` for my div as well, the white space still remain but become smaller. Anyone know how to remove the strange white space?

[image]

```
iframe {
margin: 0px;
padding: 0px;
}

.footer {
margin: 0px;
padding: 0px;
line-height: 160px;
width: 100%;
color: white;
background-color: black;
}

.footer h1 {
margin: 0px;
padding: 0px;
}
```

Comment: Please include the screenshot in the question, not as an external link. On that note, please also add a [mcve]. Otherwise we cannot help.

Comment: as @evolutionxbox said, please provide the code you've used?

Comment: It seems you have a problem with your code. However, we can't help unless we have [code or information that can reproduce the problem](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Otherwise, we are just blindly guessing.

Comment: sorry guy, i updated with the code

Answer (score 4):

Without seeing any actual code from you I can give my best guess but no promises.

First make sure that the margins on the children are `0`. Then set the font size to `0` on the parent, and reset the font size to whatever you want (default = `16px`) in the children. This will make the white space have no size.

HTML:

```
<div id="parent">
  <iframe>
  <p>Hello World</p>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#parent {
  font-size: 0;
}
#parent > * {
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 16px;
}
```

But please update the question to include some example code so we can provide a more complete answer.

Comment: may i know what is "  > * " for? sorry, still a newbie on html and css

Comment: `>` means select direct children only, and `*` is a wildcard that selects all elements. So `#parent > *` means apply this style to any element that is a direct child of #parent.

Answer (score 1):

Use Margin, Padding 0. ex:

```
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
```

in CSS. for both div and iframe